# Integrating Highcharts Sparkline with Angular JS UI Grid

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to integrate highcharts sparkline with angular ui-grid directive but unable to plot the sparkline. When we try to dynamically plot the sparklines using ui-grid nothing gets plotted. I have made necessary changes to the sparkline code as well yet unable to find what is the issue. We need age column to have highcharts sparkline. Any pointer will be of great help.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableFiltering: false,
  enableSorting: true,
}

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
  name: 'id'
}, {
  name: 'name'
}, {
  name: 'age',
  cellTemplate: '<div id="table-sparkline" data-sparkline="71, 78, 39, 66"></div>'
}, {
  name: 'address.city'
}];

$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
  .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      /**
       * Create a constructor for sparklines that takes some sensible defaults and merges in the individual
       * chart options. This function is also available from the jQuery plugin as $(element).highcharts('SparkLine').
       */
      Highcharts.SparkLine = function(a, b, c) {
        var hasRenderToArg = typeof a === 'string' || a.nodeName,
          options = arguments[hasRenderToArg ? 1 : 0],
          defaultOptions = {
            chart: {
              renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || this,
              backgroundColor: null,
              borderWidth: 0,
              type: 'area',
              margin: [2, 0, 2, 0],
              width: 120,
              height: 20,
              style: {
                overflow: 'visible'
              },

              // small optimalization, saves 1-2 ms each sparkline
              skipClone: true
            },
            title: {
              text: ''
            },
            credits: {
              enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
              labels: {
                enabled: false
              },
              title: {
                text: null
              },
              startOnTick: false,
              endOnTick: false,
              tickPositions: []
            },
            yAxis: {
              endOnTick: false,
              startOnTick: false,
              labels: {
                enabled: false
              },
              title: {
                text: null
              },
              tickPositions: [0]
            },
            legend: {
              enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
              backgroundColor: null,
              borderWidth: 0,
              shadow: false,
              useHTML: true,
              hideDelay: 0,
              shared: true,
              padding: 0,
              positioner: function(w, h, point) {
                return {
                  x: point.plotX - w / 2,
                  y: point.plotY - h
                };
              }
            },
            plotOptions: {
              series: {
                animation: false,
                lineWidth: 1,
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                  hover: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                  }
                },
                marker: {
                  radius: 1,
                  states: {
                    hover: {
                      radius: 2
                    }
                  }
                },
                fillOpacity: 0.25
              },
              column: {
                negativeColor: '#910000',
                borderColor: 'silver'
              }
            }
          };

        options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);

        return hasRenderToArg ?
          new Highcharts.Chart(a, options, c) :
          new Highcharts.Chart(options, b);
      };

      var start = +new Date(),
        $tds = $('div[data-sparkline]'),
        fullLen = $tds.length,
        n = 0;

      // Creating 153 sparkline charts is quite fast in modern browsers, but IE8 and mobile
      // can take some seconds, so we split the input into chunks and apply them in timeouts
      // in order avoid locking up the browser process and allow interaction.
      function doChunk() {
        var time = +new Date(),
          i,
          len = $tds.length,
          $td,
          stringdata,
          arr,
          data,
          chart;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
          $td = $($tds[i]);
          stringdata = $td.data('sparkline');
          arr = stringdata.split('; ');
          data = $.map(arr[0].split(', '), parseFloat);
          chart = {};

          if (arr[1]) {
            chart.type = arr[1];
          }
          $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
            series: [{
              data: data,
              pointStart: 1
            }],
            tooltip: {
              headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('div').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
              pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
            },
            chart: chart
          });

          n += 1;

          // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
          if (new Date() - time > 500) {
            $tds.splice(0, i + 1);
            setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
            break;
          }

        }
      }
      doChunk();
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eXEyqTMXF3EFMjBCMXlg?p=preview)

Comment: Just checked `$tds = $('div[data-sparkline]'),` part and it returns empty array (length = 0). Could you make sure chart are generated **after** elements are mounted?

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I have added $timeout to fix this issue.But we need to render close to thousand decimal points per sparkline which is failing. I have updated the plunker accordingly.The sparkline works perfectly when we try to render less data but plots only 1 point when the number of points increases. Not sure what can be the issue..

Comment: It looks like your plunker is still the same, could you check?